# Periodic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

A square matrix $M$ such that $M^{k+1}=M$, for some positive integer $k$, is called a periodic matrix.

1. Can we characterize the periodic matrices in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?
2. If we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by an Euclidean domain?
3. If we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by a PID?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geoff already gave a description. Here is a semigroup theory approach. $M^{k+1}=M$ means that $E=M^k$ is an idempotent,  $E^2=E$, and $EM=M=ME$. All idempotents in the matrix semigroup over $Z$ are easily described as matrices similar to diag$(0,...,0,1,1,...,1)$ (several 0's followed by several $1$'s) with unimodular conjugator. Hence we can assume that $E$ has that form. Therefore $M=EM=ME$ must have the form described in Geoff's answer. The same description holds for matrices over any ring if the structure of idempotents is similar to the above.

**Edit.**  As Geoff pointed out below, in fact since $EM=ME=M$, we get that the block $A$ in $M$ is 0, so $M$ looks like $$\left(\begin{array}{ll} 0&0\\\ 0 & B\end{array}\right)$$ where $B$ is an integer matrix with $B^k=1$. This is of course an "if and only if" description. I am pretty sure this has been known since the 50s, but I do not have time to dig it up. It should follow from the description of Green relations in the matrix semigroups.

Comment: Actually, your result is a bit stronger, since some of the matrices in my answer are conjugate. Because you have $M = EM = ME,$ you have actually conjugated them to a matrix of the form in my answer which also has $A = 0.$

Comment: @Geoff: Yes, you are right. 

Comment: @Geoff: I used a standard semigroup theoretic argument (an element of a semigroup satisfying $x^{n+1}=x$ is called a group element, it belongs to the maximal subgroup with identity element $x^n$, etc.). When you deal with a (finite) semigroup, you should start with describing idempotents, then group elements, then regular D-classes, etc. The argument works for every (not necessarily commutative) ring where the structure of idempotents is as I described.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that they are those matrices which are conjugate via a unimodular integral matrix to a matrix of the form $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 & A\\0 & B \end{array} \right),$ where $B$ is an invertible integral (square) matrix of finite order and $A$ is an arbitrary integral matrix. I think you just extend a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the pure submodule of integral vectors  with $Mv = 0$ to a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ (as column space). Then it's just a matter of seeing what the matrix looks like with respect to that basis, and computing its powers. This argument works over any PID (so, in particular, over any Euclidean domain).